# Trouble loading an ISO

Tags: iso, virtual-machines, boot

I've created a boot disk and ISO image with paragon. I boot up the Virtual pc with the disk in and I get to my recovery page.

When I am supposed to select an ISO image?

My Virtual PC doesn't acknowledge any of my physical hard drives on my host PC. I've also tried copy/paste the files into my datastore and they do not show up. I've tried the option during the set up to start with the ISO but again I am not able to browse to my external hard drive that I have stored the ISO on. VMWare will acknowledge it and say that it is connected but I can't browse to it.

Am I doing something wrong? I created the back up disk and ISO image on the external with paragon.

Comment: Which version of VMWare? ESX? ESXi? Workstation? Fusion? Player?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a virtual CD rom drive to your VM? If you have, then you should be able to either set the ISO as the default image for that virtual drive (if you haven't already booted the VM) or connect the virtual CDrom to that ISO (after booting).

If not, then you will need to add the virtual CD rom drive to the VM first.

Hope this helps,

By the way, I'm assuming that that when you refer to "Virtual PC" you are talking about your VMware Virtual Machine (VM)and not a 'Microsoft Virtual PC' VM, since the tag on this post is vmware.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a USB extenal disk? Do you have to enable/connect to the USB subsystem in VirtualPC? Can you try and copy the ISO to the local disk?